# Asynchrous callback?

Tags: javascript

How do I write my own asynchronous callback?

Like in

```
var a = function(str,callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('This should be first: ' + str + '.')
  },1000);
  callback();
}

a('hello', function() {
  console.log('This should be second.');
}
```

A link to a source is enough.
I was here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/
- http://s3.amazonaws.com/es6-promises/promise-1.0.0.js
- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js
- http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/ydt4trn5/)**

Comment: You just did it? What is your question? Why do you think that the code you told to execute 1 second after will execute *before* the code you told to execute immediately? If you want the callback to execute afterwards, then put it into the `setTimeout` anonymous function. If you want both to run instantly then remove the `setTimeout` call. Essentially, this is what you're doing: "*Tell me the time in one hour. What is the time now?*" and then you complain about the fact that it gives you the time right now.

Comment: @h2ooooooo How does jQuery animate() work then?

Comment: [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Ok. How do node.js callbacks work?

Comment: All javascript callbacks work the same way. You call them. If you run something through `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or an ajax call or similar, it usually runs asynchronous.

Comment: @user32342534: How about looking up the docs on those functions, hm?

Comment: @Cerbrus One of the posted there?

Comment: @user32342534 What is your *actual* problem, as it's obviously not how to make your own callbacks, as you've done that in the OP. Are you asking how to implement promises?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I want to make an **`asynchronous`** callback.

Comment: @user32342534 Your original question *is* asynchronous. THat's why you get `This should be second.` first and then `This should be first: ' + str + '.'` afterwards. If your code was *synchronous* then it would first wait 1000 seconds and *then* output `This should be first: ' + str + '.'` and then output `This should be second.`. `setTimeout` is by definition always asynchronous.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Last try before I go to more important trials. How to make it *synchronous* then? First comes first, second comes second?

Comment: @user32342534 Either remove the `setTimeout` function, or paste the callback inside the `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript code is asynchronous when it calls a function that's asynchronous.

So, what makes a function asynchronous?

A javascript function is asynchronous when it calls an asynchronous function:

```
function myAsyncFunction (callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){callback()}, 100);
}
```

So, how does `setTimeout` or `element.onchange` get implemented?

They're implemented in C.

For general-purpose background processing, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is the lowest-level interface to the event loop that javascript gives you. So to implement your own asynchronous functions in pure javascript you need to use `setTimeout`.

For example, if we take your original code we can make it asynchronous by simply doing this:

```
var a = function(str,callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('This should be first: ' + str + '.')
  },1000);
  setTimeout(callback,1001);
}
```

For functionality that need to process in other ways, for example run another thread or read a file or query a database, you can't do it in pure javascript. You need to modify the browser code in C. Different browsers have different ways for you to do this "officially" with plugins (that's how things like Flash and Java gets implemented). Some browsers don't allow you to do this at all.

Node.js allows you to write modules in C using the Addon API: http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html. From there on, how you make your code asynchronous is up to you - threads, select, epoll etc. But you are responsible for interfacing with the javascript event loop (most probably implemented using select/poll/epoll so you don't need to create your own).

Comment: Why not just `setTimeout(callback, 100)`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Because it's just an example. In the real world that anonymous function would do other things before calling the callback. Otherwise there's no reason to even create another function apart from setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to move the call to `callback()`:

```
var a = function(str,callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('This should be first: ' + str + '.');

        callback();
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Is this what jQuery does? I cannot find it. Or does it use the native JS `.promise()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise?

Comment: @user32342534 jQuery's implementation is naturally a lot more complex than this, but I guess you could say it's a similar idea. It certainly doesn't use native JS promises, as there are currently almost no browsers that support them.

Comment: Can you point me to the code, please?

Comment: A lot of it is in [effects.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js), but there's various asynchronous code throughout the jQuery source.